# Bad alloc exception thrown when using SVD from Eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen, svd, bad-alloc

In my application, I want to obtain the left singular vectors from a given data matrix with `double` entries, which is given in the code as

`Eigen::MatrixXd m;`

and has dimensions *45 x 904140*. Now I use the constructor for the SVD decomposition in the Eigen library as below

`Eigen::BDCSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd> svd(m, Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);`

and there, a bad alloc exception is thrown, more precisely:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA058850D8: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location
```

Comment: Can you put the full error in your question

Comment: @GenoC I did now.

Comment: Computing the full `V` matrix requires a `904140*904140` double matrix (which would take almost 6TiB). Do you actually need the full `V`, or would `Eigen::ComputeThinV` suffice?

Comment: @chtz Thin SVD would mean that `V` has dimension _9044140x45_ in this case, right? I would like to use the columns of V to span a subspace of particular size, in my application, 67. That's why I used the full SVD instead, as I would only get a subspace of 45 with thin SVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `std::bad_alloc` usually means there is not enough memory to complete your task.

You might not be able to compute the matrix that requires a 904140 x 904140 on your machine.